# Could not autowire. No beans 'here name' type found

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-security

Created a class that implements the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and added the `@Component` daemon to associate it with the Spring Security configuration object.
https://zapodaj.net/b3085e4c1cd43.png.html

```
 @Component
 public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {..}
```

IntelliJ shows me a message that

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler' type found

Comment: Does the project compile despite this error? I just ignore those errors

Comment: Make sure you have annotation config enabled.. `<context:annotation-config/>` or `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Create a bean for CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler  in Java AppConfig, if you are using Java config or create it in ApplicationContext.xml if you are using xml config

Comment: Yes. It works without problems, but still emphasizes.

Answer (score 6):

Intellij doesn't always resolve the autowiring, even if the application runs fine.

If it runs fine and you don't get compile errors ignore it.

Try running `rebuild project` to fix it.

You can add a list of packages to component scan also

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.a.b", "com.a.c" })
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler'
>   type found

This says that it cann't find bean for "**CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler**" in container. You may have defined some beans in **AppConfig** class that imports **SecurityConfig** class and have defined component scan. But the SecurityConfig doesn't know about the packages to scan and beans initialized because it is not done in its context.

Your code for securityConfig should have something like as below code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      ---- 
      ---- 
    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandlerBean() throws Exception {
      CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler  customAuthenticationSuccessHandler =new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
          //Some basic initialization
          return customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

}
```

The above code will allow you to autowire the **CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler**  class.